# Rails throwing undefined method `[]' for nil:NilClass even thought everything is working

Tags: ruby-on-rails, csv, import, nomethoderror

I have a view at the route `'memorisation'` and it has an file import for CSV file-types. When I run the import, all of the changes seem to be working fine for all 139 records. However, I am still getting an error.

```
NoMethodError in MemorisationController#import
undefined method `[]' for nil:NilClass
```

This is my controller method:

```
  def import
    require 'csv'
    all_targets = MemoTarget.order(:id).includes(:memo_level).map do |t|
      {
      :id => t.id,
      :target => t.target_number,
      :level => t.memo_level.level_number
      }
    end
    CSV.foreach(params[:file].path, headers: true) do |row|
      the_target = MemoTest.create do |test|
        test.student_id = row["student_id"]
        test.teacher_id = session[:user_id]
        test.memo_target_id = all_targets.find {|t| t[:level] == row["memo_level"].to_i and t[:target] == row["memo_target"].to_i}[:id]
        test.result = true
      end
    end
    redirect_to '/memorisation', notice: 'Student memorisation current targets imported'
  end
```

The line `test.memo_target_id = all_targets.find {|t| t[:level] == row["memo_level"].to_i and t[:target] == row["memo_target"].to_i}[:id]` is throwing the error.

In my server log, all the expected changes are being made as shown by the `SQL COMMITs`. After the commits, the controller should redirect back to the `memorisation` page.

```
   ...
   (0.7ms)  COMMIT
   (0.3ms)  BEGIN
  SQL (0.5ms)  INSERT INTO "memo_tests" ("student_id", "teacher_id", "memo_target_id", "result", "created_at", "updated_at") VALUES ($1, $2, $3, $4, $5, $6) RETURNING "id"  [["student_id", 139], ["teacher_id", 1], ["memo_target_id", 30], ["result", "t"], ["created_at", "2015-09-13 08:08:05.205922"], ["updated_at", "2015-09-13 08:08:05.205922"]]
   (0.6ms)  COMMIT
Completed 500 Internal Server Error in 6145ms

NoMethodError (undefined method `[]' for nil:NilClass):
  app/controllers/memorisation_controller.rb:33:in `block (2 levels) in import'
  app/controllers/memorisation_controller.rb:30:in `block in import'
  app/controllers/memorisation_controller.rb:29:in `import'


  Rendered /Users/Javu/.rbenv/versions/2.2.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/actionpack-4.2.0/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/templates/rescues/_source.erb (135.6ms)
  Rendered /Users/Javu/.rbenv/versions/2.2.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/actionpack-4.2.0/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/templates/rescues/_trace.html.erb (69.8ms)
  Rendered /Users/Javu/.rbenv/versions/2.2.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/actionpack-4.2.0/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/templates/rescues/_request_and_response.html.erb (13.1ms)
  Rendered /Users/Javu/.rbenv/versions/2.2.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/actionpack-4.2.0/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/templates/rescues/diagnostics.html.erb within rescues/layout (270.0ms)
Cannot render console with content type multipart/form-dataAllowed content types: [#<Mime::Type:0x007fd4d2cd4c28 @synonyms=["application/xhtml+xml"], @symbol=:html, @string="text/html">, #<Mime::Type:0x007fd4d2cd4868 @synonyms=[], @symbol=:text, @string="text/plain">, #<Mime::Type:0x007fd4d2ccc2a8 @synonyms=[], @symbol=:url_encoded_form, @string="application/x-www-form-urlencoded">]
```

I've looked through it with `byebug` to see if there was any problem with the import or the 139th record, but everything seems to be fine.

I want to know what's causing this errot and how to rectify it.

Comment: I wonder if this could be caused by an empty line at the end of your csv...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`row` is `nil` in your CSV file that is why you are getting this error, try below code it will work.

```
def import
  require 'csv'
  all_targets = MemoTarget.order(:id).includes(:memo_level).map do |t|
    {
    :id => t.id,
    :target => t.target_number,
    :level => t.memo_level.level_number
    }
  end
  CSV.foreach(params[:file].path, headers: true) do |row|
    next if row.all?(&:blank?)
    the_target = MemoTest.create do |test|
      test.student_id = row["student_id"]
      test.teacher_id = session[:user_id]
      test.memo_target_id = all_targets.find {|t| t[:level] == row["memo_level"].to_i and t[:target] == row["memo_target"].to_i}[:id]
      test.result = true
    end
  end
  redirect_to '/memorisation', notice: 'Student memorisation current targets imported'
end
```

Comment: Thanks! That was true, the last 20 rows were blank. I tried adding the line of code but the code threw the same error, so I deleted the empty rows manually and all was fine. **Thoughts on how to refactor the above to account for that?**

Comment: updated answer with ` next if row.all?(&:blank?)`. this will check if row is blank

Comment: You can try little better way `CSV.foreach(params[:file].path, headers: true, skip_blanks: true)`